# How may I install clang v8 on 32-bit Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, 18.04, clang

I have this, but it's not working:

```
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | apt-key add - \
    && add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-8 main" \
    && apt-get -qq update \
    && apt-get -qq install \
        clang-8 \
        libc++-dev \
        libc++abi-dev \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-8 100 \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-8 100
```

I get:

> E: Unable to locate package clang-8

## EDIT

Looks like the 32-bit version of Clang is not available in their repositories. So, I'm completely out of ideas. I can't use their repositories, but I also can't upgrade to Ubuntu 19 (which does have a `clang-8` package in the official repositories). Ubuntu 19 doesn't have the other packages I need (not shown above), such as `libssl1.0-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading the LLVM/clang source code for the version you want (http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) and building it yourself. There are some instructions in the INSTALL.txt file inside the source code tarball.

Comment: There is no INSTALL.txt in the LLVM source package

Comment: @void.pointer The ["Clang source code" link](http://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/cfe-8.0.0.src.tar.xz) at http://releases.llvm.org/download.html gives a file called cfe-8.0.0.src.tar.xz that is about 13 MB. Unpack it and look inside:
`tar xf cfe-8.0.0.src.tar.xz ; cd cfe-8.0.0.src/ ; ls`.
Then you should see the INSTALL.txt file.